# std::bad_alloc but works in the end

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, memory-management

I'm developing an application on VS 2008 Express Edition on Debug mode. When instantiating a new pointer of a class I have created, I get a std::bad_alloc exception. Since it is in Debug mode, I click on 'break' in the window that has appeared and I try to resume the program by pressing on the 'play' button.

What happens next is rather unexpected: the program works as it should.

This error happens when I'm instantiating an array of `Matrix` objects (my class) using `Matrix* vec = new Matrix[maxItr + 1];` (I've checked and `maxItr` is equal to five when the error is raised). This class has a few integers members and a pointer to a char. This pointer is not allocated in the default constructor (it is even set to 0), so I eliminated this as a cause of the error. (No extremely large blocks of memory are requested).

Does anyone have an insight on that?

Comment: You need to give some code to explain your question.

Comment: Likely when you get the exception, it is the OS saying the memory is not allocated for you. The behavior at that point is undefined, you can still write to the memory but you don't have any guaranteeing...does this make sense? WHat OS are you using? I may be incorrect because depending on the OS you cannot write to arbitrary memory but this is one possible cause of what you are seeing.

Comment: bad_alloc is also thrown when the heap manager has detected heap corruption.

Answer (score 0):

Does the constructor of your class have a `new` in it? Or maybe a `new` that's buried inside another class, such as a vector? If so, maybe you're getting the allocation for the vector of objects but one or more of the objects contained within is malformed.